# How to specify connectionstring explicitly for Entity Framework DBContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My `BaseDBContext.cs` uses the `BaseDBContext` key in `connectionstrings` by default.

How can I explicitly set which key to use? I.e. if I want it to use `DefaultConnection` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) constructor of `DbContext` class

```
public class BaseDBContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseDBContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```